# R: For Loop with the Colon Operator and the Length of an Empty Vector

Tags: r, for-loop

Till now I worked fine with my for loops though vectors using:

```r
foo = c("one","two","three")
for (bar in 1:length(foo)) {
    print(bar)
}

#[1] 1
#[1] 2
#[1] 3
```

However, I've noticed that the loop is accessed even if the vector is empty:

```r
foo = c()
for (bar in 1:length(foo)) {
    print(bar)
}

#[1] 1
#[1] 0
```

Of course I could use an IF statement (if (length(foo)!=0)), but I'm sure there is a better way to do this.

Maybe I have a too "pythonic" strategy since there I wouldn't have the problem with

```py
foo = []
for bar in foo: 
    print(bar)
```

What is the best way to prevent an access of the for loop if my vector is empty?

Comment: What about not using the index: `for (bar in foo) { print(bar) }` ?

Comment: foo = c("one","two","three")  ------  for (bar in foo) { print(bar) } -> that is especially good when directly accessing the vector elements. Is this a newer functionallity in R? When I learned R ~2015 I was teached to use 1:lenght

Comment: I know, it is not the same result as in your original code. Eventually you do not need explicit indexing: then you can loop through the elements. Even `sapply(foo, print)` is returning a list of length 0. The funcionality in R is not changed since 2003 (when I learned R).

Comment: ok so both "seq_along" and "indexing" work perfectly fine for me (even though they make other things, of course) and I learned a lot though this post. However: what are the forum rules which answer to accept? or is there a way to fusion answers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the better way is to use `seq_along` to loop over a vector.

```
foo = c("one","two","three")
for (bar in seq_along(foo)) {
   print(bar)
}

#[1] 1
#[1] 2
#[1] 3

foo = c()
for (bar in seq_along(foo)) {
  print(bar)
}
#Prints nothing
```

edit based on jogos comment: `Indexing` can be used to access the vectors elements directly:

```
foo = c("one","two","three")
for (bar in foo) {
   print(bar)
}

#[1] "one"
#[1] "two"
#[1] "three"

foo = c()
for (bar in foo) {
   print(bar)
}
#Prints nothing
```

Comment: @NelsonGon `seq_along` loops over the length. Since the length is 0 it doesn't print anything whereas `1:length` create a sequence from 1 to `length` of `foo` which is 0 so ultimately it creates as sequence `1:0`.